# Return rows between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have `ItemsRent` table,

```
ID | ParentID | SubID |       StartDate      |       EndDate       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 100      | 102   | 2014-09-09 17:40:00  | 2014-11-09 17:40:00 |
2  | 70       | 73    | 2014-08-09 14:20:00  | 2014-12-09 13:40:00 |
```

The dates are in sql format.

My input dates are:

```
InputStartDate: 2014-09-09 18:00:00
InputEndDate: 2014-10-09 13:47:00
```

And i want to return the best row only of the dates are between two dates. So for example:

```
Lets call StartDate as S, and EndDate as E.
And input dates will be InputStartDate as IS, and InputEndDate as IE.

S                E
|----------------|
         IS              IE
         |XXXXXXX--------|
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Storing UNIX-style timestamp values in the database is probably a bad idea. Why are you doing this? Also, you can use the `BETWEEN` operator most of the time.

Comment: The question is poorly worded. Maybe giving some examples of rows you would expect to be returned and some rows you don't would help.

Comment: @Laurence I've changed the question. Please take a look

Comment: First, fix the dates so they are stored using native SQL date/times.  Why spend all your effort transposing strings into dates and preventing indexes from making queries run faster?

Comment: @Bonik what date are you using to compare to that range? does S have to be greater than IS and IS less than E and IE less than E and IE greater than S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will produce a result matching your illustration. It will find all rows where any time at all was spent between `InputStartDate` and `InputEndDate`, and output a modified date range that is clamped by `InputStartDate` and `InputEndDate`.

```
SELECT ID, ParentId, SubId,
       MAX( InputStartDate, StartDate ) AS Date_Start,
       MIN( InputEndDate, EndDate ) AS Date_End
FROM  `itemsRent` 
WHERE InputStartDate <= EndDate AND InputEndDate >= StartDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I would say to use the BETWEEN operator, but since you are storing both the start and end dates in the table, this would get more complicated than it needs to be.  If you assume that the start date being stored is before the end date, you only need to perform two checks.

```
SELECT * FROM `itemsRent` WHERE `StartDate` > 1410285600 AND `EndDate` < 1410356820
```

This verifies that the start date of the item takes place after the specified start date.  The issue with this is that it does not check if it takes place before the end date.  Instead of explicitly writing this check, you can make sure of this by checking that the item's end date takes place before the specified end date.

NOTE: Might cause issues if the start date does not occur before the end date.  If this is a possibility, then you will need to explicitly write these checks.  This would be a good case in which to use the BETWEEN operation.

Comment: I've changed the question. Please take a look

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pull out the max end date in the table as the high date?

```
SELECT * 
FROM itemsRent
WHERE (InputStartDate BETWEEN startdate AND end date) 
  AND (InputEndDate BETWEEN startdate AND enddate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is currently looking for rows whose `EndDate` is **earlier** than your provided `StartDate` or **after** your provided `EndDate`. I don't think that is what you want.

If you want rows that both StartDate and EndDate are between your provided dates (lets call them `your-start-date` and `your-end-date`), your query should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `itemsRent` WHERE `StartDate` > your-start-date AND `StartDate` < your-end-date AND `EndDate` > your-start-date AND `EndDate` < your-send-date
```

Comment: @Bonik The row in your example doesn't have both dates between the given dates.

Comment: @Laurence Yeah i got that i need to change to my values. Please see the updated question